# Fuzzy search algorithm for western European languages (in my case Swedish)

Tags: c#, .net, fuzzy-search

I'm looking for a fuzzy search implementation that works well with western European languages.

Which algorithm works the best and where can I find an implementation in C#?

**Update**

Soundex adapted to swedish:

- http://escuelle.blogspot.com/2008/03/swedish-soundex.html

NYSSIS implementations:

- http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=497137
- http://dropby.com/PhonKey.cs

Levenstein:

- http://www.merriampark.com/ldcsharp.htm

Impressive Java library:

- http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html

But I still doesn't know which one is better for western European languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked NYSSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Soundex is a well known algorithm for matching similar sounding words.
Search Google for "soundex c#" for an endless list of suitable implementations and explanations.

You may have to map å,ä,ö to a,a,o if that is not included in the code you pick.

Comment: Soundex is optimized for the English language. NYSSIS seems to be a better fit for languages with extended characters. There are also several other alternatives.